# How to manipulate the result of two parameters with arithmetic operations?

Tags: c++, c++11, calculator

## Partially Solved

Check bellow to see how i solved this **silly** big problem.

---

I am currently trying to learn how to preform any mathematical operation (in the console) to the result of the previous mathematical operation, for example:

```
user inputs 1
            +
            2
            system("cls");
            3
            *
            2
            system("cls");
            6
            /
            2
            system("cls");
            3
```

so on and so forth.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double num,num2, res;
string fchoice;
char choice;


system("cls");
cout << "0\b";
cin >> num;
system("cls");

cout << num << "\n\n";
cout << num << endl;
LOOP:
cin >> choice;
cout << "\n";

switch(choice)
    {
    case '+' :
        cin >> num2;
        res = num + num2 ;
                system("cls");
    cout << res << endl;
        break;

    case '-' :
        cin >> num2;
        res = num - num2 ;
                system("cls");
    cout << res << endl;
        break;
    case '/' :
        cin >> num2;
        res = num / num2 ;
                system("cls");
    cout << res << endl;
        break;
    case '*' :
        cin >> num2;
        res = num * num2 ;
                system("cls");
    cout << res << endl;
        break;
    }



return 0;
}
```

But the problem is, i don't know how to store the last result.
So my questions are (if it's not too much trouble for you guys):

- <s>How can i store the result so i can manipulate it later on?</s>
- How to make the console reset (or delete) the previous results if the user enters a number and not an operation, and make the console ready to make new operations?

  If you guys could give me some hints, i'll thankful.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that am a beginner.

#### Last Edit:

All i had to do was simply add this line to rewrite the previously defined `double num` to `num = res;` just before the `goto LOOP;` so it would always return to the beginning.

Comment: Your `goto` usage really just emulates a simple loop. Change the label to a loop introduction and change the `goto`s to `break`s in order to exit the switch.

Comment: Is all of the user input going to happen in the same program call, or should the data be available ("persist") between executions?

Comment: @user1717828 The last result must persist and be saved for next operation.

Comment: @BeyondNero, ahh, you will need to write the result to a file if you want the information to persist between executions.  All variable data is lost each time the program exists.

Comment: @user1717828, no, without exiting the program, as in the same instance, not different instances of the program. I am not trying to save it for next time some reopens the program, only in the same instance of it.

Comment: @BeyondNero Off topic from you question, but a little advice to help improve your code for you to learn now, so that you don't fall into these traps later on, in your '/' case you should have a check to see if your num2 variable is 0 or not. If it is 0 then you should printout a message to the user as undefined division by 0 then break otherwise do the division! Since you are new, just don't want you to start learning bad habits now that will progress when projects get much larger!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should stop using goto statements and start using loops for this. (BTW I can see your label, but not your goto statement? ). To answer your second question, you could add a default statement in the switch statement, which will make it go back to the top if not an

```
 default:
    goto (any label at beginning of program);
```

Or if you were using a while loop, just clear all your values in the default statement.

As a footnote, why write the

```
cout<<res<<endl;
```

4 times? just write outside the switch once.